# How to get a single item from my Amazon Dynamodb Table

Tags: vb.net, amazon-dynamodb

My .Net code below is always returning a search.Matches.Count of 0 even though the movie is in the table. I've literally searched the whole internet but have not been able to get an answer, even on Amazon's AWS Developer website.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong? I appreciate your help. I'm totally new to this.

```
client = New AmazonDynamoDBClient(config)
table = Table.LoadTable(client, "MovieTable")

scanFilter = New ScanFilter
With scanFilter
    .AddCondition("KeyCode", ScanOperator.NotEqual, MovieName)
    .AddCondition("Status", ScanOperator.Equal, "In")
End With
search = table.Scan(scanFilter)
If search.Matches.Count = 1 then getMovieName
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/MDynamoDBScanScanRequest.html) explains, "Scan", a function which is supposed to go through the entire database, cannot go through the entire database at one fell swoop. Instead, it goes through it 1MB at a time, and after 1MB of data it returns to the caller, and you're supposed to ask to continue in the next page (again, see the documentation on how).

In your case, you have a very specific filter which matches only one item, but still - Scan will return after having **read** 1MB of data, even if none of the items in this 1MB match your request. It doesn't wait until 1MB of results have been collected! So in your use case it is not surprising that you're getting an empty result set, with `LastEvaluatedKey` set signalling that there are more pages to read.

By the way In your use case, where you are looking for just one item, doing a Scan of the entire database is obviously not a great choice (unless you're only doing this for debugging). a GetItem or Query operation will make more sense, if you can, and maybe a secondary index would be useful if you're searching by items not in the key.